# How to use Emacs michelson-mode with Tezos sandboxed client?

Tags: michelson, sandbox

The Emacs michelson-mode relies on being able to call Tezos client. How can you use the Tezos [sandboxed](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/user/sandbox.html) client for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you initialize the sandboxed client, running `which tezos-client` command will give you the absolute path for the sandboxed client. In Emacs you can then set the variable `michelson-client-command` to this path.

Answer (score 1):

You can open emacs in the same terminal as you ran:

```
eval `./src/bin_client/tezos-init-sandboxed-client.sh 1`
```

When running this script, a path corresponding to the sandbox tezos-client (it looks like `/tmp/tezos-tmp-client.XXXXXXX/bin`) is added to the PATH env variable.

Alternatively, you may want to use the following command (with the correct path) in another terminal:

```
PATH=/tmp/tezos-tmp-client.XXXXXX/bin:$PATH emacs file.tz
```

Also, you can have a look at https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/user/sandbox.html for more information about the sandbox mode.